# SQL Error "No viable alternative at input'case'"

Tags: sql, case, sql-order-by, jaspersoft-studio

I am creating a report in Jaspersoft Studio, and want to sort the output based on parameters provided by the user. To do this, I am using CASE WHEN in an ORDER BY clause. However, the query editor throws an error on the first CASE keyword - "No viable alternative at input 'case'". I have limited SQL knowledge, so most of this is new to me. I modeled this CASE WHEN off of other examples, and I can't figure out why this editor is throwing an error.

```
select "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."PROTOCOL_NO" as protocol_no,
            "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."PI_NAMES" as principal_investigator,
            "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."STATUS" as current_status,
            "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."SPONSOR" as sponsor,
            CAST("RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."IRB_EXPIRATION" as DATE) as expiration_date,
            "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."IRB_EXPIRATION_NA" as expiration_na
 from "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"
    join "RV_PROTOCOL_DETAILS"
        on "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."PROTOCOL_NO" = "RV_PROTOCOL_DETAILS"."PROTOCOL_NO"
 where (
        "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."STATUS" = 'OPEN TO ACCRUAL'
        OR "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."STATUS" = 'CLOSED TO ACCRUAL'
        OR "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."STATUS" = 'SUSPENDED'
    )
    AND (
        "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."IRB_EXPIRATION" is null
        or "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."IRB_EXPIRATION" < $P{currentDate}
        or "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."IRB_EXPIRATION_NA" = 'Y'
    )
    AND $X{IN, "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."PI_NAMES", selectedPI}
    AND $X{IN, "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."SPONSOR", selectedSponsor}
    AND $X{IN, "RV_PROTOCOL_DETAILS"."DT4_REPORT_TYPE", dt4Type}
order by
    case
        when $P!{sortBy} = 'Protocol no.' and $P!{sortOrder} = 'Ascending' then "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."PROTOCOL_NO"
        when $P!{sortBy} = 'Pis' and $P!{sortOrder} = 'Ascending' then "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."PI_NAMES"
        when $P!{sortBy} = 'Current status' and $P!{sortOrder} = 'Ascending' then "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."STATUS"
        when $P!{sortBy} = 'Sponsor' and $P!{sortOrder} = 'Ascending' then "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."SPONSOR"
        when $P!{sortBy} = 'Expiration date' and $P!{sortOrder} = 'Ascending' then "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."IRB_EXPIRATION_NA"
        when $P!{sortBy} = 'Expiration n/a?' and $P!{sortOrder} = 'Ascending' then "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."IRB_EXPIRATION_NA"
    end ASC
    case
        when $P!{sortBy} = 'Protocol no.' and $P!{sortOrder} = 'Descending' then "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."PROTOCOL_NO"
        when $P!{sortBy} = 'Pis' and $P!{sortOrder} = 'Descending' then "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."PI_NAMES"
        when $P!{sortBy} = 'Current status' and $P!{sortOrder} = 'Descending' then "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."STATUS"
        when $P!{sortBy} = 'Sponsor' and $P!{sortOrder} = 'Descending' then "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."SPONSOR"
        when $P!{sortBy} = 'Expiration date' and $P!{sortOrder} = 'Descending' then "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."IRB_EXPIRATION_NA"
        when $P!{sortBy} = 'Expiration n/a?' and $P!{sortOrder} = 'Descending' then "RV_PROTOCOL_BASIC"."IRB_EXPIRATION_NA"
    end DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are really storing your Parameter $P{sortBy} with extra quotations inside the string you don't need to use the exclamation mark in $P!{..}

`when $P{sortBy} = 'Protocol no.' and $P{sortOrder} = 'Ascending'` should work.

Using $P!{sortBy} in your CASE WHEN statement will likely result in something like `CASE WHEN Pis = 'Pis' a...`.

[Here is some more info about $P!{](https://milangadajaspersoft.blogspot.com/2018/11/p-p-x-parameters-in-jasper-report.html)